# AWS Lambda - ensure complete processing - data persistence, event publishing etc

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Say I have some code like this in a lambda function:

```
public void handleRequest(final S3Event s3Event) {
        //stuff removed for brevity
        
        fooRepository.add(foo);
        eventPublisher.publish(someEvent1);
        eventPublisher.publish(someEvent2);
}
```

Where the `eventPublisher` is a wrapper for an `sqsClient` which send messages to an sqs queue.

Is there a pattern/approach that can be used to ensure that if one command fails the whole lot gets aborted/reverted? (fails and succeeds as one unit)

e.g. in the above, say the publishing of `someEvent1` fails an exception might get thrown causing the event to be reprocessed by the lambda - this *could* then result in duplicate data being added to the db via the call again to `fooRepository.add(foo)`...

Comment: See [Creating Idempotent Lambda Handlers with DynamoDB](https://matthewbonig.com/2019/06/04/idempotent-lambdas/).

Comment: Ultimately you cannot do that since the downstream system do not support a commit-rollback mechanic. You can try to perform an action and then track that that action has been performed, e.g. in a DynamoDB, but even a DynamoDB has a failing requests ever other day.

Comment: @jarmod @luk2302 thanks - so basically it requires implementing a mechanism that does not perform a DB update based on a duplicate requestId? With respect to the downstream services that would consume `someEvent1` `someEvent2` they _may_ get duplicate events so should be idempotent too?

Comment: Your problem is two-fold - handling duplicate messages (easy with a dynamoDB) and handling all intermediary crashes (generally impossible with multiple down-stream systems). If you can make sure all downstream systems are idempotent you are good to go, but that is quite difficult a lot of the time :)